# What is the discard option in `stty -a`? It uses `^O`

Tags: linux, terminal, stty

In `stty -a`, there's an option for `discard = ^0`. I've googled around, and the closest documentation I get is from: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-17.html which says

> ^O flush (or discard). Not yet implemented in Linux (but proposed). Sends output to /dev/null.

I tried it several times and nothing happened. If it isn't implemented, why is it bound to `^O` then?

Answer (score 3):

#### What is the discard option in `stty -a`?

There is a patch to document this setting:

> The equivalent of this is 'flush', but that was never documented
>   as an option (though was output with stty -a).  Therefore use
>   the more descriptive name, also generally used on BSD systems.
>
> Note even though this setting seems ineffective on Linux, supporting
>   the setting is useful to allow terminal programs to receive
>   the default ^O character code.

Source [[PATCH] stty: document the 'discard' character setting](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2015-01/msg00068.html)

Comment: So currently it has no effect?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai "supporting the setting is useful to allow terminal programs to receive the default ^O character code."

Comment: I don't understand? I should be able to send `^O` to terminal programs regardless? It works for every other control character.

Answer (score 0):

Though `stty` shows `^O` is bound to that useless action, with `bindkey -s "\C-o" "cd - \n"` , I can make use of `^O`, a keybind easy to press.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding more information on what `bindkey` is. It is a [builtin specific to zsh(1)](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins) and probably some other shells. GNU Bash (default in GNU/Linux) and ksh (default in OpenBSD) don't have a `bindkey` builtin.